# PyQGIS creating grid layer using extracted extent and rounding up/down

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, vector-grid

I have the following code that is meant to extract the extent of a raster, and round the extents up or down to the nearest 10000, then create a vector grid using this rounded extent at 10,000m spacing

```
input = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(raster_test)[0]
coord_system = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:7855')
xmin = (input.extent().xMinimum()) 
xmax =  (input.extent().xMaximum()) 
ymin = (input.extent().yMinimum()) 
ymax = (input.extent().yMaximum())

course_xmin_round = math.floor(xmin / 10000.0) * 10000.0
course_xmax_round = math.ceil(xmax / 10000.0) * 10000.0
course_ymin_round = math.floor(ymin / 10000.0) * 10000.0
course_ymax_round = math.ceil(ymax / 10000.0) * 10000.0

course_extent = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(course_xmin_round, course_xmax_round, course_ymin_round, course_ymax_round) 

coarse_grid = processing.run("native:creategrid", {'TYPE':2,'EXTENT': coarse_extent,\
    'HSPACING':10000,'VSPACING':10000,'HOVERLAY':0,'VOVERLAY':0,'CRS':coord_system,\
    'OUTPUT':QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT})['OUTPUT']
```

When I run this even though printing the the coarse extent gives me value of

```
390000.000000,460000.000000,7800000.000000,7890000.000000
```

my output grid does not appear to be correctly originating from these coordinates:

[image]

I would expect this top left polygon to have coordinates like this:

left: 390000
top: 7890000
right: 400000
bottom: 7880000

when I copy the extracted extent from the script and run the grid tool manually I get the desired results

[image]

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: What version of QGIS 3 are you on? I replicated with 3.14.16-Pi and had no such issue.
I assume your project properties and layer etc are all in the same EPSG?

Comment: What does `input.crs().authid()` give you, also EPSG:7855?